# How to group author's books annotation by kind?

Tags: django, orm, python-3.6, django-annotate

I'm playing with the book/author django documentation.

Is there a way to get books from author grouped by kinds in an array agg? (pgsql)

The following query is correct but I need information from authors table.
 `Books.objects.values('kind').annotate(rating_min=Min('rating'),.. Etc.`

Can I get author's books rating range grouped by kind ?

`Author.objects.values('book__kind'). annotate(rating_min=Min('book__rating'))`

```
Author.objects.annotate(rated_books=ArrayAgg('book'),...?
```

Expecting something like

```
author.rated_books =[
    {'kind': 'fantasy', 'rating_min' : 2,
'rating_max' : 5, 'total' : 6},
]
```

Any idea to combine both?

Comment: What do you need that for? What are you going to do with `rated_books`?

Comment: Is it uncommon query with orm? I just want to group ratings by kinds by author to understand how good an author is in several kinds (fantasy, romance,...)

Comment: What is uncommon is stuffing so much data into a single field. Depending on the models and what you want to do with the data, there is probably an easier way to do that than with a dictionary appended to `Author`.